# How to determine the number of columns in a UNIX shell

Tags: python, shell, terminal

I want to determine the number of columns in a window for my sh/bash-script. I'm now using `tput cols`, but I found out that on some platforms (Synology) the `tput` library is not available.

I know there's a C library for this, but a binary is not an option.

Python3 is an option, but I haven't found anything in the help files...

An alternative to `tput cols`, if at all possible...

Comment: Can an answer be written for a *specific* UNIX shell, or does it need to work on all of them?

Comment: That is, `sh/bash` is a lot like saying `C/C++` -- `sh` and `bash` are two different languages; they aren't mutually compatible. (bash is *mostly* a superset of the POSIX sh specification, but there are a few places where it breaks the POSIX sh specification even in compatibility mode and isn't formally a valid `sh` implementation).

Comment: It would be nice if it worked on all sh-shells where python3 also works.

Comment: Python works even on systems with no shell installed at all. :) -- but I take your point; that means the easy answer (involving `SIGWINCH` updating the shell variable `COLUMNS` on bash) isn't available.

Comment: OK Charles, but how do you find out the number of colums in Python then?

Comment: One solution is to create an tput alias that always returns 80, when tput is not available...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The Right Way: Python Standard Library

Python 3 supports [`shutil.get_terminal_size()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.get_terminal_size), which itself falls back to [`os.get_terminal_size()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.get_terminal_size) should Python not have been invoked from a shell which exported `COLUMNS` and `LINES` (as bash does, when running in interactive mode with a TTY attached).

---

#### Less Right: Asking A Shell From Python

If you want to get this information through a shell, *some* shells (including bash) will expose it in interactive mode. The following (while lacking adequate error handling) showcases this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess, sys
p = subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-i'],
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=sys.stderr)
out = p.communicate(b'''printf '%s\n' "$COLUMNS" "$LINES"''')[0]
cols, lines = out.split(b'\n')[:2]
print("Cols: {}; lines: {}".format(int(cols), int(lines)))
```